# Show: $(X,d_X)$ is complete $\Leftrightarrow $ $f(X)$ is closed in $(Y, d_Y)$ ($f: X \to Y$ is an isometric embedding)

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, isometry, complete-spaces

I have the following task:

> Show that a metric Space $(X,d_X)$ is complete if and only if for every isometric embedding $f: X \to Y$ in another metric Space $(Y, d_Y)$ it holds true that $f(X)$ is closed in $Y$

Any ideas or hints on how to prove this? Thanks in advance.

(I know that since $f$ is isometric it preserves the distance between two points and that since it's an embedding it's injective and continous. I further know that for every metric space there exists a completion i. e. there exists a metric space $(Z, d_Z)$ and an isometry $\phi : X \to Z$ so that $\phi (X) $ is dense in $Z$. But i don't really know how to pack all this together and get the prove)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more difficult part is, in fact "$ \Leftarrow $", i.e the fact that $(X,d_x)$ is complete, but according to what you have written you have all the necessary ingredients.

Consider the obvious inclusion $i$ of $(X,d_x)$ into it's completion $(X_c, d_{X_c})$ (which, also obviously, is an isometry) and consider the image of a Cauchy sequence $x_n$ under this inclusion. This is, of course, also a Cauchy sequence since $i$ is an isometry. Since the target $X_c$ is complete, $i(x_n) $ converges to $x_c\in X_c$, and since the image is closed, $x_c=i(x)$ for some $x$. Since $i$ is an isometry, $d(x_n, x) = d(i(x_n), x_c)$ which tends to $0$, so $x_n\rightarrow x$ and $X$ is complete w.r.t $d_X$

I leave the other direction, which is a bit simpler, to you (or someone else).

Comment: Why exactly do you know that if the image $i(X)$ is closed in $X_c$ that there exists a $x\in X $ so that $i(x)=x_c$ (i. e. how do you know that $i$ is surjective)? I think i don't really understand what it means that $i()$ is closed **IN** $X_c$

Comment: @DeltaChief One criterion for a subset of a metric space $X$ to be closed is as follows: $A$ is closed in $X$ if and only if for every sequence $x_n$ with $x_n \in A$ which converges to some $x_* \in X$ the conclusion $x_* \in A $ is true. I just applied this to the sequence $i(x_n)$ and the fact that, by assumption, the image of $i$ is closed (in $X_c$).

Comment: Ah ok, thanks a lot, i have an idea for the other direction: since $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous and $X$ is both open and closed (clopen), i can say that it is closed and then use that preimages of closed sets are closed: $f^{-1}$ continuous and $X$ is closed $\Rightarrow$ ${f^{-1}}^{-1}(X)=f(X)$ is closed. Is this reasoning correct ? (I'm not sure about saying that $X $ is closed).

Comment: @DeltaChief Hmm, $f^{-1}$ is defined only on the image of $f$. The idea goes into the correct direction, though. If you are not sure about how to deal with closed sets you should drill into the topic until it's clear. But you can argue along the lines of the criterion I just told you about. Consider $f(x_n)\rightarrow y\in Y$. So $f(x_n)$ is Cauchy. Then $x_n$ is Cauchy (Here we apply $f^{-1}$, but only on an allowed set), so there is $x$ such that $x_n\rightarrow x$. Then $f(x)=y$ (why?), and we see that $y\in f(X)$, so $f(X)$ is closed (using the property from my previous remark).